# Can I map between values inside enums?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, enums

I create enum which has two values: brand name and brand code. 
I want to know the brand code by inputting the brand name. 
And I also want to know the brand name by inputting the brand code. 
Can this problem solved using Enum? or other code is more effective? I want to make the code as shorter as possible

I have created following code to search the code of a brand. If I want to do vice versa, I can create another Hashmap and method to convert the code into a brand. But is that the effective way to solve it?

```java
public enum Brand{
  COLA("cola", "CL8935"),
  BREAD("bread", "BR2810"),
  SNICKERS("snickers", "SN4423");

  private static final Map<String, String> BY_BRAND = new HashMap<>();

  static {
    for (Brand brand : values()){
       BY_BRAND.put(brand.code, brand.brand);
    }
  }

  private final String brand;
  private final String code;

  public static String convertToCode(String brand){
    return BY_BRAND.get(brand.toLowerCase()).toString();
  } 
}
```

Comment: It's perfectly effective. Or you can just loop if it's just a few items. Or use a BiMap.

Comment: You seem to be conflating a number of things here and haven't shown the rest of your code.

Comment: @chrylis I didn't put all because my problem is inside here. The rest of a code is just a main class calling the method inside this enum. A snippet to call ``Brand.convertToCode("the brand input");``

Comment: just a *note*: using `code` as key in `put` but `brand.toLowerCase` in `get` - sure none will be returned (assumind `brand` is the first value in constructor like `"cola"` and`code` the second value in constructor, like `"CL8935"`) - seems like mixed both cases here (and effective is a very broad term)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger oops, the key should have been the ``brand``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update - Adding the full enum (with imports)**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.Function;

enum Brand {

   COLA("cola", "CL8935"),
   BREAD("bread", "BR2810"),
   SNICKERS("snickers", "SN4423");

   private final String brand;

   private final String code;

   Brand(String brand, String code) {
      this.brand = brand;
      this.code = code;
   }

   public static Brand findBy(String value, Function<Brand, String> extractor) {
      return Arrays.stream(Brand.values())
            .filter(brand -> extractor.apply(brand).equalsIgnoreCase(value))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse("Either a default or throw exception here");
   }

   public String getBrand() {
      return brand;
   }

   public String getCode() {
      return code;
   }

}
```

**Original**

You could use a static findBy method as an alternative to the map. This would allow you to pass in the value and method reference for the getter which will be used to compare the values stored within the enum.

The difference here would be performance (as maps would be faster), the fact that you would be returning the enum and that you most likely would want either a default enum value or to throw an exception on no matched being found. Below is an example

```
 public static Brand findBy(String value, Function<Brand, String> extractor) {
      return Arrays.stream(Brand.values())
            .filter(brand -> extractor.apply(brand).equalsIgnoreCase(value))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse("Either a default or throw exception here");
   }
```

And this can be called like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      Brand brand1 = Brand.findBy("cola", Brand::getBrand);
      Brand brand2 = Brand.findBy("BR2810", Brand::getCode);
   }
```

Comment: is this method created inside the Enum class? Because I couldn't resolved the Arrays type. The quick fix doesn't suggest me to import it either. hmm

Comment: Yes I will update my answer with the full class (including imports)

Comment: The question is " I want to know the brand code by inputting the brand name. 
And I also want to know the brand name by inputting the brand code."  So to fully answer the question you need two more methods like: `public static String getBrand(String code) {
    return findBy(code, Brand::getCode).getBrand();
   }`

Answer (score 1):

Simple static method in `Brand` should do:

```
  public static String getBrand(String code) {
       for(Brand b : Brand.values()){
           if(b.getCode().equals(code)) return b.getBrand();
       }
       return null;
   }
```

Similarly you can write a `getCode(String brand)`

---

Edit: assuming the two attributes do not have the same value, you can check do the bi-di mapping in the same method:

```
  public static String getOtherAttribute(String value) {

       for(Brand b : Brand.values()){
           if(b.getCode().equals(value)) return b.getBrand();
           if(b.getBrand().equals(value)) return b.getCode();
       }

       return null;
   }
```

If the two attributes may have the same value you can add an argument (flag) to the method's signature to tell which attribute you want to retrieve.

Comment: yeah sure, this method will work..  I just wondering whether I can mapping bi-directional relationship inside one method :D